# 2013 - Powershell Enable columns

Tags: 2013, powershell, column

I'm creating sites, subsites and lists via PS. And I need to "enable" the version/size columns, in lists I created.

I don't want to create them because they already exist. In graphical mode, I just have to check the column's box I want, then the column appear in lists.

But in PS, I can't find a way to do it.

I find things like this : ([sources](http://snahta.blogspot.fr/2013/05/sharepoint-powershell-create-new-list.html))

```
  $myCustomList = $myTestWeb.Lists[$ListName]

    #Add columns

    $spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text 

    $myCustomList.Fields.Add("TextField",$spFieldType,$false)
```

But it does not work. If someone can rescue me :)

Thanks in advance,

Nico.

P.S : I apologize for my bad english :(

Comment: I can't add "Hello" at the beginning of my post... It dissapears automatically =/

Comment: For good reasons ;) You should add the fields to the default view, not the list itself (since as you say, they are already on the list) http://www.google.com/search?q=viewfields.add+powershell

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean. The default view is an object (or attributes) of the list itself ? I do $list=$web.Lists["NameofMyList"], then I have to do something with the $list, Am I right ? I'm gonna search deeper with what you gave to me :) Thanks for you reply

Comment: A list has one or more Views that renders and displays list items from the list. you find them under $list.Views . From what I get from your question, you want to show some fields that are already on the list (but not visible)? If so, then you have to add the fields to the Views you are using

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I want to see the verionning and the file size. I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417841/sharepoint-2010-loop-through-all-document-libraries-create-a-view-and-set-it
This is good. I'm now able to do a $list.DefaultView.ViewFields  . Now question is : where can I find all english name of columns, as FileSizeDisplay. Because I want the file versionning. Thank you a lot @Robert Lindgren

Comment: Great, so by clicking list settings you see all columns, if you click one, check the URL of the page you land on. There is a parameter called Field, the internal field name is assigned to this :)

Comment: This is nice, for the version, it's "Version()" . But when I do a $biblio.DefaultView.ViewFields.Add("Version"), then an update, nothing appear ... And I d'ont see any File Size column :s

Comment: You also need to call view.Update() on the view. Check the examples on google

Comment: Already done when I did : $view.viewfields.add($list.Fields["FileSizeDisplay"]), then $view.Update().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9981/discussion-between-robert-lindgren-and-nico)

Comment: I can't log in for the chat =/ But btw, IT WORKS ! It was my bad, of course ;) So I did : $view = $list.DefaultView, $view.ViewFields.Add("FileSizeDisplay"), $view.ViewFields.Add("_UIVersionString"), then $view.Update() and finally $list.Update(). i think I didn't update both list & view. Thanks a lot, really @Robert Lindgren ! P.S : Last thing I have to find then english name for "Commentaires d'archivages", I have nothing to click on. "Commentaires d'archivage" means comments when you change the version of a document. I'm gonna google it :) Thanks again !!!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out

Comment: Ok I find : http://blog.bendsoft.com/2011/06/list-your-sharepoint-document-libraries-on-external-sites/ ;) You have all the SharePoint name. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you ever used SP Manager? Try it out, it can help you with finding internal names and a lot of other stuff: http://spm.codeplex.com/